# Sentence correction question

Tags: sentence-choice

**Despite all obstacles** (a) I **will complete** (b) this **training on** (c) self control **by next month** (d) [No error]

It's a question from a test. One of the bold sections is erroneous or there is no error.

I was unable to find any error but the answer says (b). With no explanation given, I do not understand why it is wrong and what should it be.

Comment: [...] this **training with** [...]

Comment: Self control is like an innate property. It is something you can work _with_ and certainly not _on_.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh it's a poor question, because one *can* take training in self control, but it would still be (c) with *in* preferred.

Comment: @WeatherVane True. I completely forgot about self-control as a subject/course. If seen in that context, it can also be [...] **this training in** [...]. Thanks!

Comment: I understand you found some punctuation to be incorrect, but *Despite all obstacles, I will*[..]  has been taken verbatim from the original question. In this case I presume it will be better revert to the previous form, although it might be incorrect.

Comment: We were not talking about punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing this sort of test, I know what they want you to do.

The last part says "by next month", so the verb form they want is "will have completed".

The alternative is to change "by next month" to "next month" (but this changes the meaning to match the grammar, not the grammar to match the meaning, so is not what the test writers want you to do)

It is debatable if this is actually a mistake, but the future perfect form does go naturally with a "by {time}" phrase.

Comment: I like your guess.. an upvote from me; however, It actually is really debatable.. that is: we have to clearly define the discrepancy between "I will finish it by next month" vs. "I will finish it next month". Semantically, there smells to be a point, that "by next month" implies no later than that.. yet, it's blurry to draw a sharp line in between.

Comment: Thank you. This conforms to the answer given. I wasn't aware of such grammar rules, which made me unable to understand the answer.